# SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK: [api.github.com]

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

All my GitHub Actions checks are failing because of the following error
`SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK: [api.github.com]`. It seems to be an error on the virtual machine. Can anyone help decipher what's wrong? Here is [the full error message](https://github.com/epiverse-trace/bpmodels/actions/runs/5601340030/jobs/10245062388?pr=125).